# Joomla banners are not rotating

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5, banner

I need to rotate some banners. But they are not rotating, just displayed both:
[image: Banners]

Are there any ideas, why it is happening and how can i fix this problem?

Comment: I configured client, category and banner. Than i created new banners module.

Comment: Make sure there is no js error and share your site url....s

Comment: [WebSite](http://specialpressie.com)

Answer (score 3):

I know this question is a little old, but I just finished thoroughly reviewing the banners component in Joomla 3.0

If your banners are not rotating, I suggest the following:

1. Checking the banner module's **Randomise** setting is set to **Sticky, Randomise**
2. Check your banner's **sticky** settings, having just one sticky banner can cause them not to rotate
3. Check your banner module's **cache** setting, try changing it to no caching
4. Ensure your banner module's **Count** (under basic options in Joomla 3) is not too high. If you have 3 banners and set the count to 3, then it will show all three. Setting the count setting to one will make sure only 1 shows and they rotate
5. Check your banner's Max impressions setting (under the banner details) tab. If the banner has hit the max impression limit, it will not be included in the rotation of the banners.

I've documented these, and added more thorough info and screenshots [here](http://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/edu/joomla-3/banners/rotating).

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 versions of jQuery running on your site which are conflicting, which I why I think they aren't working properly.

JoomShopping component and PPC Simple Spotlight mdoule are using it. Try opening file in the simple spotlight folder that includes jquery and replace it with this:

```
<?php
    if(!JFactory::getApplication()->get('jquery')){
       JFactory::getApplication()->set('jquery',true);
       $document->addScript(JURI::root() . "modules/mod_ppc_simple_spotlight/js/jquery-1.5.min.js");     
    }
?>
```

Comment: Id didn't help.
Btw, by rotation i understand: every page refresh there's new banner. [like here](http://dazzlingqueen.com) - bottom banner.